# Windows XP scandisk is frozen

Tags: scan-disk

As the title says, I ran scandisk on an external disk. It froze after 5 minutes. Right now it's been 3 days. I need to stop it, but the cancel button doesn't work.

This problem happened to me once, and forced quit the program : bad idea, lots of datas were lost.

So I need to obviously stop it, how can I do it in a way that is safe for my computer?

Comment: If its unresponsive you need to kill the process. The data loss may have been due to a hardware fault previously uncovered by the repair attempt.

Comment: thx for the answer! I read somewhere that it locks sector and doing so may kill scandisk and leaving sectors locked and unacessible, is it prevented when kill with CTRL+ALT+DEL?

Comment: thx!! about the title it's XP, I god mixed between 2 computers!! thanks

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim it may do, but if its crashed its crashed. If its half way thought a re-write you might lose a couple files. Backups backups backups.

Comment: So the process has stalled.  If that is the case then any method you use to kill the process will result in the same outcome.  It stalled because of a hardware issue, because you don't run this tool, on a drive that exhibits zero problems.  Whatever happens is going to happen at this point you can't prevent what will happen.

Comment: thanks for the help! I stopped it and it seems fine that time

Comment: I wonder if it's worth leaving this question or I should delete it?<